# Why does F# require quotes in explicit generic type parameters?

Tags: generics, f#

**Explicit type parameters** must be specified with a ' before the letter:

```
type MyType<'t>() = ...
let f<'t> (x: 't) = ...
```

Why are plain letters like

```
let f<t> (x: t) = ...
let f<T> (x: T) = ...
```

not allowed?

The question is only about the way how to specify **explicit** type parameters.

Comment: Those examples are less common than `let f(x: 't)=x` or just `let f(x)=x` which show *why* `'t` is used. Type annotations aren't needed in general, unless F#'s type inference has trouble making the function generic. I suspect the real question should be why `<'t>(x: 't)` is allowed when `(x: 't)` is the common case

Comment: Could it just be the defined syntax?

Comment: F# tries to minimize ceremony and make types transparent. The compiler will try to infer the actual types and treats the methods as generic whenever possible. The preferred syntax is `let f x = x`, which is already generic.  `x: 't` is used when we need to "help" the compiler by telling it it shouldn't infer a concrete type, or when we want to tell it that two parameters must have the same type. `<T>` or `<'t`> aren't needed at all and I suspect they're allowed to make it easier to convert non-F# (ie C#) code.

Comment: Thx. I clarified that my question is ONLY about WHY the syntax requires '

Comment: `only about the way how to specify explicit type parameters.` because that can't be a completely different syntax from the common one.  Angle brackets are used when the simpler syntax fails. It would be *very* awkward if such a rare definition used a completely different syntax.  If you want an official answer you'll have to ask Don Syme, but I'd guess the answer would be similar.

Comment: F#'s syntax largely comes from OCaml, and that's how OCaml does it. Simple as that.

Comment: F# had generics before .NET and C# got them, so it's not a case of why `<>` isn't used everywhere but why it's even allowed. F# always used `'t` for generics. `<>` is a special case

Comment: I guess it comes from fact that functions rarely have full type signature and only some parameters are annotated. Without quote it would be possible to write `let f (x: a) = x`, and compiler would have to find type `a`, and if it doesn't find it, then treat `a` as generic parameter. It would open new category of hard to identify errors. Allowing to write explicit generic parameters without quote will only allow do same thing other way, which is generally avoided by language creators

Comment: Well, In let f (x: a) = x the compiler knows that a is not a generic type parameter, since there is no <a> , this is how a C++ or C# operates I guess.

Comment: @citykid, you're right, but in F# it's possible to use generic parameter without declaring it first: `let f (x: 'a) = x`

Comment: *you* are right ! ;)